# How is Cosmic Microwave Background's temperature measured?

Tags: observational-astronomy, cosmic-microwave-background, radio-telescope, black-body

How do Cosmic Microwave Background missions/telescopes measure CMB temperatures? I understand that CMB has Planck's spectrum. So I was thinking one strategy could be to measure the [spectral radiance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiance) corresponding to different frequencies coming from a certain direction and then compared these data points with theoretical [Planck's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law). Is this technique practically feasible?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what is being done.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape, this could be a source: https://astro.uni-bonn.de/~kbasu/ObsCosmo/Slides2019/CMB_Part1.pdf (slide 19)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is what is done.  This is shown in an old xkcd comic https://xkcd.com/54/

[image]

The curve shows the distribution of frequencies in the CMB, and by using the marked value of the maximum you can determine the value of T, the apparent (red-shifted) temperature of the CMB

Comment: Source: https://astro.uni-bonn.de/~kbasu/ObsCosmo/Slides2019/CMB_Part1.pdf (slide 19)

Comment: In Physics SE we can [ask questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/420542/83380) about XKCD's, in Biology SE [not so much](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/93026/27918). However in Astronomy KXCD's can serve as answers!